# iCloud server side wildcard mail rules

Tags: icloud, email, mail-rules

I couldn't find any information on how to set up wildcard rules in iCloud mail. I want to forward mail from any sender of a certain domain to another address.

What exactly is the syntax of the *message is from* field?

**@domain.com** or ***@domain.com**?

Do I need to set up another rule to remove these messages from the inbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For these cases I just use

> from domain.com

with

> move to folder

as the action. You don't have to delete it from the Inbox afterwards, the move takes care of that.

Comment: Are you referring to mail.app or icloud.com? I'm looking for a solution on the website.

Comment: The above applies to rules on icloud.com (which are fairly limited anyway).

Comment: Thanks! I was a bit confused as the rules cannot be rearranged in priority. So a *move* rule could theoretically make a *forward* never catching if set up higher.